# Having trouble selecting dropdown with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am currently trying my hand at web scraping in order to automate some searches for work.  The website that I'm scraping is here:
[Wisconsin RETR](https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced) (under RETR Search -- Advanced in case the page doesn't display correctly) .  I'm trying to select "County Name" from the drop-down so I can then figure out how to add a name, click add, then click search (lots of future steps to figure out). My initial difficulty is that I can't seem to access the element.  After viewing the page source, the id=sCriteria but when I use `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sCriteria')`, I get an error saying "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":[id="sCriteria"]"}.

I know the element is there because I can see it on the page source, but no matter what I've tried after scouring the internet for the afternoon, nothing seems to work.  Also, when I enter this into Python,

```
ids=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[id]')
for ii in ids:
    print(ii.get_attribute('id'))
```

I get a list of `id`s that I can located in the webpage but it doesn't contain the one I need.  I think it has to do with the id=sCriteria embedded within a table that is located inside Form1, but honestly I have no idea and I'm pretty sure that it's not located within a frame. Also, here is a screen capture of the html associated with the element I'm trying to select. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)     
driver.get("https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#btAgree"))).click()
box=Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#sCriteria"))))
box.select_by_index(1)
```

To simply grab that box and select any element you can use the following wait for the element. As well as clicking the agree button beforehand.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Arundeep, I'll give your suggestion a try when I get back to my computer and let you know. So will I always need to do the wait.until when something is influenced by a click event?  Sorry for the additional question, just trying to figure out how I can apply this knowledge moving forward and for others that may have this question in the future.  I'll be web scraping a couple other sites and really want to learn how to do this better.